# How can I print debug a C++ Win32 DLL?

Tags: c++, c, windows, debugging, winapi

I am currently working on a project that relies on injecting a DLL into another process, so (AFAICT) standard debugging tools don't work. What I've been using instead is `#define DEBUG(_msg) MessageBoxA(nullptr, _msg, "Debug", MB_OK)`.

This has the issue that it blocks the current thread until I click on the message box, which screws up my code in certain places and/or freezes the process I injected the DLL into.

So, how should I print a debug message with the Win32 API that I can view elsewhere, and continue running code instantly?

Comment: log it to a file, and tail the file.

Comment: ...I'm a moron lol

Comment: Standard debugging tools will in fact work fine, just instead of your DLL use the injected process as the debug target. And instead of printing to a regular console print to the debugger's trace window (at the lowest level use OutputDebugString though msvc for one has helpful wrappers around that).

Comment: Use `OutputDebugString()`, and view its messages with [SysInternals DebugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview) when the target process is not running inside a debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio a running process can be debugged.

In the menu Debug look for Attach to process.

Then breakpoints can be triggered like normal.